# Copying files from network in command line

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I want to copy files(type `.scr` files) to my network (domain connected ) connected using command prompt or through copy command; is it possible?

How do I copy files or share the files throughout network using command prompt?

Comment: You can use `copy` to copy single files using a UNC path. Multiple *.scr files in different paths, you'd have to use a tool like forfiles which will loop through a subdirectory to find the file(s) you are wanting to copy.

Answer (score 3):

In all Windows versions you can use `xcopy` instead of `copy`.

> In computing, XCOPY is a command used on PC DOS, MS-DOS, OS/2,
>   Microsoft Windows, and related operating systems for copying multiple
>   files or entire directory trees from one directory to another and for
>   **copying files across a network**.

Article and examples on Wikipedia: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY)

---

In windows Vista and later versions you can use `robocopy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx) to copy files to network locations.

Answer (score 0):

Files are copied right the same way across the network: the difference is how the file name ("path") begins: `C:` will be for a local file on the C: drive, while `\\SERVER\SHARE` will instead be a "shared directory" on the station named SERVER; rest unchanged. You can use `copy` for file(s) in a single directory, or commands like `xcopy` or `robocopy` to copy hierarchies (trees) of files.

To share the files, you need administrator's rights on the "server" machine and create a "share"; this can be done with command-line [`net share share=`...](http://ss64.com/nt/net_share.html) or using the Windows Explorer.

Note: because of previous abuses, `.scr` files might be subjected to anti-virus policy on the other station (the "server") you are connecting to when doing a file copy across the network.